# Button back to main screen not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This problem I got is a little hard to explain but I simplify and make it as easy as possible. 
 
The Statement: 
As it is obvious in the following picture ,there are 9 divs which is sensitive to click and when you click in any of them another screen appears which is also obvious in second picture down here. [image: divs image]

The Problem:
 In the first DIV ,when I click back to Main Menu ,everything works fine but ,when I click on Second Div and click back to Main Menu ,the button doesn't work. I used the same backtoMain() method for both but obviously something is wrong.

[image: second image]

The javascript code I use to make backToMainMenu button work:

```
            function hideAllDivs () { /* the function that hides all divs */

              jQuery('#thirdVision').hide();
              jQuery('#forthVision').hide();
              jQuery('#fifthVision').hide();
              jQuery('#sixthVision').hide();
              jQuery('#seventhVision').hide();
              jQuery('#eightthVision').hide();
              jQuery('#ninethVision').hide();
              jQuery('#tenthVision').hide();
              jQuery('#eleventhVision').hide();
              //jQuery('#secondVision').show();
            }
            function returnToMenu () { /* the function that shows main screen which is secondVision */
              hideAllDivs();
              jQuery('#secondVision').show(1400); /* shows secondVision "First Picture" in 1 and a half second */
            }
            jQuery('#backToMain').click(function(e){ /* the function responsible for when "backtoMainMenu" button is clicked */
                returnToMenu();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
```

I've been working on it for about 3 days but couldn't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: does each div container has separate back menu button? Or you used a common button for all of them?

Comment: I use this this code in each div for the back menu button : <a href="#" class="button big green" id="backToMain"><span> Back To </span>Main Menu</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nima you used same id for multiple back buttons, Instead use class in case of IDs

The html link should be

```
<a href="#" class="button big green backToMain"><span> Back To </span>Main Menu</a>
```

and the script code should be

```
jQuery('.backToMain').click(function(e){ 
       returnToMenu();
       e.preventDefault();
});
```

Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 0):

Use classes instead of ID like:

***[jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/emicim/3/edit)***

get the `index()` of the clicked element to retrieve the relevant content using the `.eq()` method

HTML: sample

```
<div id="container">

  <div class="box">Title 1</div>
  <div class="box">Title 2</div>
  <div class="box">Title 3</div>
  ...

  <div class="content">Content 1</div>
  <div class="content">Content 2</div>
  <div class="content">Content 3</div>
  ...

  <button id="backToMain">BACK TO MAIN</button>

</div>
```

jQ:

```
(function( $ ){

  $('.box').click(function(){        
    var myIndex = $(this).index();
    $('.content').eq( myIndex ).show();
    $('#backToMain').show();
  });

  $('#backToMain').click(function(e){ 
      $(this).hide();
      $('.content').hide();
  });

})(jQuery);
```